# Photo Editor SDK to a react-native application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, photoeditorsdk

[image]I already have a running react-native application that is using a camera and Images. I need to be able to filter, crop and rotate these images.
How can I install the Photo Editor SDK to React Native Application without getting any problems? 
this is the package that I need to install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/photo-editor-sdk-react-native

Comment: What photo editor SDK?  Do you have one picked out (asking for library suggestions is off topic here)?  What problem are you having installing it?

Comment: please check the picture above and the link